# Powershell refer to dynamic variable name

Tags: powershell, variables

I have a reason why I don't want to use an array. But is it possible to use variable folder$i in the Remove-Item command

```
Set-Variable -Name "folder1" -Value "c:\windows\temp\1\*"
Set-Variable -Name "folder2" -Value "c:\windows\temp\2\*"
Set-Variable -Name "folder3" -Value "c:\windows\temp\3\*"


for ($i=1; $i -le 3; $i++)
{
Write-Host "folder to delete : Remove-Item –path folder$i -recurse"
Write-Host "$(folder$i)"
Remove-Item –path "$(folder$i)" -recurse
}
```

Comment: As mentioned by [@Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey)'s answer. AFAIK, *there isn't* (*shouldn't*) be any reason to refer to a dynamic variable. Instead of a **array**, did you consider a [**hashtable**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-6)?

Answer (score 1):

generally speaking, NOT using an array for this is ... a *really good* self-foot-gun situation. [*grin*]

however, if you have found some bizarre reason to NOT use the logical method, the following will work. it uses the `Get-Variable` cmdlet to do the actual work.

```
$Var1 = 'Variable_One'
$Var2 = 'Two_Variable'

foreach ($Index in 1..2)
    {
    Get-Variable -Name "Var$Index" -ValueOnly
    }
```

output ...

```
Variable_One
Two_Variable
```